American: Can credit be converted to frequent flier miles?
With American Airlines, can credit be converted to frequent flier miles?

Probably depends on why you have the credit, your status, and who you talk to on the day

Unlikely, but you can always call and ask.
A straight out conversion is probably a no go. Flight credits are intentionally designed to be restrictive and difficult to use: the airline wants to keep the money ideally without giving you something in return, especially if you are not a regular customer. Credit typically expire within a year whereas for AA the miles have a 2 year life time. A conversion would be a backdoor to extend the life of the credit, which AA really doesn't want.
Some airlines offer to buy extra miles for cash when booking a flight, but I don't think you could use flight credit for that (if they even offer that). Even if that would be a possible, the conversion rate is typically very poor and you would have to book a flight (at which point you could use your credit directly).
Some airlines do allow paying with a combination of miles and cash but American is not one of them.
